# How to read file and add to array based on specific input range

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

This is content of my text file:

> Temperature : Fri Dec 12 1:35:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 22 Celcius-
>       Temperature : Fri Dec 12 1:36:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 25 Celcius-
>       Temperature : Fri Dec 13 2:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 25 Celcius-
>       Temperature : Fri Dec 14 2:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 25 Celcius-
>       Temperature : Fri Dec 14 3:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 27 Celcius-
>       Temperature : Fri Dec 15 3:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 99 Celcius-
>       Temperature : Fri Dec 15 4:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 69 Celcius-
>       Temperature : Fri Dec 15 5:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 68 Celcius-

How can I for example only add readings between specific range and add it to my array?

For example if I input 13 and up to 15 date the array should have readings between Dec 12 and Dec 14 and hours of 2 to 3. Not getting anywhere with this...

```
public static String readwrite2(String namefile) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(namefile));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("specify date from: ");
    String a = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("specify from hour:  ");
    String b = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("specify up to which date: ");
    String c = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("specify up to which hour: ");
    String d = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your input is " + a + b);
    String line;

    String currentdate=a, currenthour=b;
        String nextdate = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(currentdate) +1);
        String nexthour = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(currenthour) +1);
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("Dec "+currentdate+" "+currenthour)){
            words.add(line);
        }
    currentdate=nextdate;
    currenthour=nexthour;
    }
}

for (String s : words)
    builder.append(s);
    reader.close();
    return builder.toString();
}

List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(builder.split("-")));
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.println(myList.get(i));
}
```

So the outcome should give readings of:

```
Temperature : Fri Dec 13 2:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 25 Celcius-  
Temperature : Fri Dec 14 2:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 25 Celcius-  
Temperature : Fri Dec 14 3:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 27 Celcius-  
Temperature : Fri Dec 15 3:12:48 GMT 2014, Reading: 99 Celcius-
```

I would really appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can split(`String.split(",")`) each line by ',' initially,you will get an array of Strings such as :
`Temperature : Fri Dec 12 1:35:48 GMT 2014` and `Reading: 22 Celcius-`

A second split on the first element of this array will give you another array,whose second element is  date time format:
Fri Dec 12 1:35:48 GMT 2014

Have your filtering logic here and proceed.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question, but the results I get are similar to my outcome in question, as I used "-" to split my results. The main issue is I want specific readings from text file based on the input. Thanks for your feedback though

Comment: You need to filter the date also, EEE MMM yy HH:mm:ss z yyyy